# Trouble with WebClient and Thread management

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, webclient

I've been scratching my hair out trying to figure out this problem. I'm using a WebClient control that reads in a dynamic URL. There is data that I am trying to extract that isn't in the HTML source when retrieved from the Server but is rendered later with Javascript/AJAX.

I've used multiple methods including `Thread.Join()` and `BackgroundWorker` with zero results.

I'm now trying to use a `async` method but to be honest I'm totally lost as to what I'm doing.

Here is my code:

```
protected void retrieveDataSource(int matchId_val)
{
ManualResetEvent completionEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += delegate(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
source = e.Result;
completionEvent.Set();
};
wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://na.lolesports.com/tourney/match/" + matchId_val));
}

protected void LoadWebPage()
{
retrieveDataSource(matchId_val);
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(source);
}
```

`source` is a global variable that is set to `null` initially. When I run this code the `DownloadStringCompleted` argument is never triggered and thus the source is never changed from `null`. When it reaches `doc.LoadHtml(source)` I'm given a null exception. **IT SHOULD BE NOTED** that if I hit 'Continue' then the breakpoint will arrive at the `DownloadStringCompleted` function which is beyond me.

If anyone can help me I'd greatly appreciate it as I've already spent my entire morning trying to wrap my mind around the issue.

Comment: You can not retrieve data that does not exist in your source at the point in time when you are trying to get it. You would need to know the AJAX source the page is using and call it directly, just like the page you are hitting does to access the data. Assuming that is permitted by the owners of the AJAX source.

Comment: I was able to extract the data succesfully using `Thread.Join()` but would run into either a MemoryException or the `Thread.Join` would indefintely hang. It was really inefficient only being able to scrape 2-3 entries before indefinitely being suspended but at least I know there is a way to extract the data sucessfully without knowing the AJAX source.

Answer (score 2):

There are ultimately a number of difficulties you may well run into as you attempt this. The bottom line is that to get at dynamically-generated content, you have to render the page, which is a lot different operation from simply downloading what the HTTP server gives you for a given URL.

In addition, it's not clear what you're using to render the web page. You are using a class named `HtmlDocument` and a method named `LoadHtml()`. This suggests that you are using Html Agility Pack, but your question is silent on that point. To my recollection, that library doesn't render HTML; but I could be wrong or have out of date information.

All that said, there is a very clear bug in your code. You create an event handle, which is apparently used to signal the completion of the asynchronous operation, but you never wait on it. This means that the thread that started the I/O will just keep going and attempt to retrieve the result before it is actually available.

One way to address that would be to wait on the event handle:

```
protected void retrieveDataSource(int matchId_val)
{
    ManualResetEvent completionEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += delegate(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        source = e.Result;
        completionEvent.Set();
    };
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://na.lolesports.com/tourney/match/" + matchId_val));
    completionEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

Of course, if you're just going to make the thread block while you wait for the operation to complete, that raises the question of why are you using asynchronous I/O at all? Why not just call `DownloadString()` instead, which will automatically block until the operation is done.

I also advise against the use of a class field for the purpose of passing data from a called method to the caller. It would make more sense here for `retrieveDataSource()` to return the result to the caller directly. Were the code written in that way, the issue with the thread synchronization would have been more readily apparent, as you likely would have noticed the method returning before that value was actually available.

But if you insist on using the asynchronous method, the above change should at least resolve your thread synchronization issue.

Comment: First off, thank you for your response.

When I use `DownloadString` the HTML Element that I am looking for results in `<span class="robust-link-container"></span>`. When using `Thread.Join` and `Application.DoEvents()` despite sometimes having the program hang or memory exceptions I would at least be able to access the HTML Element that results in `<span class="robust-link-container">
<a class="btn-secondary" href="http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/TRLH3/1001160016?gameHash=7fec292772911f14" target="_blank">Player Builds and Game Analysis</a>
</span>`

Comment: Also to help I've also found the static Javascript file that is used to render the `<span>` which is found here: http://na.lolesports.com/profiles/lolesports_profile/modules/custom/esports/esports_players/js/build_end_game_stats.js?npr04g

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "using Thread.Join and Application.DoEvents()", but in a correct, well-written implementation neither would be necessary. The above should address the null reference issue, by ensuring that the operation has completed, but it will of course block the thread that's waiting, which could cause other problems. Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly how your code is structured, I'm afraid only advice no more specific than the above can be offered.